# SVN Lock error: Lock token URI has bad scheme

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I recently tried to lock a file in my SVN checkout, and I got the following error:

> svn lock -m "a comment" File1.pas
>
> svn: warning: W160037: Lock token URI ' 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server>exit 0 
>   ' has bad scheme; expected 'opaquelocktoken'

Someone else got the error first (Windows 7), then I replicated it on my test repo (Windows 8) with a fresh checkout on a different file. I originally used Tortoise v1.8.9, and then replicated it using the command line utility v1.8.11. The repository is VisualSVN Server 3.2, but I also tried upgrading the test repository to version 3.3. In short, it is showing up on all the files I have tried using TortoiseSVN and SVN CLU, for VisualSVN Server 3.2 and 3.3.

The only reference to this I have found is here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201107.mbox/%3C20110719205702.GA8224@daniel3.local%3E. It shows the code being used to generate the error. It seems like the repo is sending back:

C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server>exit 0

instead of the opaquelocktoken information. At this point I am thinking it is a bug in VisualSVN Server or we have something configured on VisualSVN Server incorrectly, although I could not find any pertinent settings. Open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in VisualSVN Server, but an error in post-lock hook script that was configured by an administrator. Contact the server administrator asking him to fix the hook script.

Comment: I am as close as we come to an SVN admin. We have a pre-commit hook to require a comment, but otherwise they were all 'exit 0;'.  Removing the pre-lock and post-lock hooks did it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello!  What if we need to fix the script instead of remove it?  If you can help, check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548032/svn-lock-hook-error-expected-opaquelocktoken.  We're a little desperate here at work.  Thanks!